# C, откуда 3 байта?

Tags: c

Вот простенький код, на экран выводит число равное 3, почему? откуда взялись эти 3 байта

```
  struct student {
            char name[20];
            char sex;
            int age; 
            float mark;
    };

    struct student s2;
    int main( void )
    { 
        printf("%d", sizeof(s2) - sizeof(s2.sex) - sizeof(s2.age) - sizeof(s2.mark) -sizeof(s2.name)); // = 3
}
```

---

и еще один вопрос той же темы

```
   union rec {
        int a[5];
        struct student st;  
    } r;

    int main( void )
    { 
        printf("%d", sizeof(r) == sizeof(student) );
    }
```

почему выдает истину, если на самом деле ни какая не истина, 5 * 4 байтов разницы

Comment: Очевидно, после char sex добавляется 3 байта, чтобы смещение следующего int было кратно 4. Оптимизация, проще говоря. По идее, если char sex перенести в конец, то размер структуры будет соответствовать расчетному, однако если создать массив таких структур, начало каждой из структур скорее всего будет опять же выровнено по адресу кратному 4, т.е. те же самые +3 байта.

Comment: @Евгений536 такие вещи должны быть в описании компилятора со средствами, как такое поведение менять.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Эти три дополнительных байта - результат так называемого выравнивания. Суть его заключается в том, что данные помещаются в памяти не всегда "вплотную", вслед друг за другом, а по адресам, которые кратны размеру поля. Скажем, если int на данной платформе имеет размер 4 байта, то поле данного типа будет размещено не сразу вслед за предыдущим полем, а по ближайшему адресу, кратному четырем. Все эти хитрости с выравниванием служат одной цели - увеличению скорости работы, так как процессору проще обращаться к данным по "выровненном" адресам. Кстати, если бы ваша структура состояла только из однобайтных полей, то этого эффекта по понятным причинам бы не было

По поводу второй части вопроса тоже вполне объяснимо - это вытекает из самой сущности union, который, в отличие от структур, хранит данные в одной и той же области памяти, и его размером является размер его максимального поля. Максимальным по размеру является st, следовательно sizeof(r) равен sizeof(student)

По первой части вопроса почитайте [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/142662/) и [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/90580/), по второй части - например, [здесь](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_(%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85))

Кстати:

> ААА, не могу понять, где лежать будут эти 20 байт???)))

вот вам простая аналогия - представьте себе выключатель, которым вы включаете/выключаете свет. Вы могли бы использовать вместо одного выключателя два разных рубильника. Один - чтобы  включить, а другой - чтобы выключить свет. Но удобнее иметь все это в одном выключателе. То есть когда свет включен, вы не можете его включить еще раз, когда выключен - не можете еще раз  выключить. union - это нечто похожее - когда вы пользуетесь одним его полем, вы не можете пользоваться другим (точнее можете, но это не имеет смысла и приведет к ошибкам). Аналогия, конечно, кривовата, но, может, с ее помощью вам будет проще понять это

Comment: на лекциях также было написано, но вот а где память под массив в объединение? вот до этого я вообще не могу допереть, как это в одной области..? в одно области они не смогут поместиться, 20 байт не хватит для массива

Comment: union rec {

        int a[5];

        struct student st;  

    } r;

ну вот в этом объединение есть структура и массив из 5 чисел, я понял что память выделиться только под st(так как размер больший) а вот под массив он как память выделит?

Comment: >в одно области они не смогут поместиться, 20 байт не хватит для массива

так их будет не 20. Я еще раз повторю - sizeof(r) будет равен размеру максимального поля вашего объединения. Максимальным по размеру в нем является st типа student, размер которого равен 32 байтам (или сколько там он будет занимать на вашей платформе).

Comment: Под массив он будет использовать ту же самую память, что и под st - в этом и есть смысл union и его главное отличие от struct - данные внутри union как бы "перекрывают" друг друга, хранясь в одной и той же памяти. Если вы запишете что-то в st, то тем самым сотрете то, что было в a

Comment: ААА, не могу понять, где лежать будут эти 20 байт???)))  ну ладно все равно спасибо!

Comment: они будут лежать в том же самом месте. Просто записывая одно поле, вы тем самым будете "затирать" другое. Это может иметь смысл в случае строгой экономии памяти, но такие случаи весьма редки, и даже при необходимости использовать union нужно весьма осторожно. Попробуйте сами догадаться, что может случиться при неосторожном обращении с памятью, которая является общей для всех полей

Comment: пример вообще классный, все дошло , спасибо вам огромное!